# Tailwind media queries for padding

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I cannot make a simple media query for the padding of an element. I work with NextJs but it is not the problem because my custom break points work for everything else but this :

When I have a class like `className="p-2 sml:p-4"` the `p-2` overwrites the other class. I think it has to do with the `!important` attribute given to `p-2` by tailwind.

How to make this simple thing ? What am I missing ?

PS: I repeat, this problem has nothing to do with the media query itself, `className="bg-black sml:bg-white"` works perfectly fine. The `sml:` is my custom media query that is triggered at 576px, and I repeat, works very well.

---

Edit: Minimal code to reproduce

```
<main className="p-2 sml:p-4">
  <div className="w-full h-12 bg-black"/>
</main>
```

---

Edit: Config file for tailwind version 3.1.2

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  important: false,
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  plugins: [
    require('tw-elements/dist/plugin')
  ],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sml': '576px',
      'mdm': '768px',
      'nrm': '992px',
      'lrg': '1280px',
      'max': '1564px',
    },
    extend: {
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: What screen size are you testing this in?

Comment: @Edrian I tested it on a 2560×1600px and on 1920x1080px displays. Can you tell me why it can help ?

Comment: I was asking because according to Tailwind's docs, their breakpoint system is mobile first. Meaning p-2 will apply for ALL sizes until you provide the next breakpoint, which in this instance is sml:. Can you try changing "sml" to "sm"?

Comment: `sml` is your custom breakpoint?

Comment: @Edrian ```sml``` works very well, so trying ```sm```did not change anything, still showing ```p-2``` with any screen size.

Comment: @DaxPatel ```sml``` is my custon break point at 576px, it works very well.

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin could you provide me a source code in https://play.tailwindcss.com/ or in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @DaxPatel I don't think it can help, when I edit the code of play.tailwindcss.com, it works well, the property ```p-2``` does not have a ```!important``` attribute there (when inspecting). Question edited with minimal code to reproduce. Any idea why I could have ```!important``` ?

Comment: Which version of Tailwind CSS are you using? Also, if you're adding a custom breakpoint with `sml`, can you please include your `tailwind.config.js` file where these are defined?

Comment: @KirkBeard Question edited

Comment: I can't replicate the issue locally here, but I've noticed that you're using `tw-elements/dist/plugin`, which includes Bootstrap components. Is it possible this is importing Bootstrap's `p-2` class which uses `!important` for their utility classes? I've had a quick look through their [Github repository](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Tailwind-Elements) but I'm not 100% if that's the cause or not. Their SCSS variables do set `$enable-important-utilities` to true, which would append `!important` to all the padding/margin/etc helper classes.

Comment: @KirkBeard Nice lead, no idea how to resolve that if it's the case. You got any ?

Comment: What you're describing is not default TailwindCSS behaviour. Something else is adding the `!important` to the styles.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the problem is that the `!important` attribute is added to the `p-2` class. You can disable whether or not Tailwind's utilities should be marked with `!important` in your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  important: false,
}
```

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration

Comment: I already tried but i does not work.. Thanks for your answer tho, no idea what is happening..

Comment: Have you tried setting `important: true` to see if forcing `!important` works?

Comment: It does not work..